# Dynamically name PHP variable in a Loop

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I am having trouble dynamically naming my PHP variables when doing a foreach loop. Here is my code:

```
$count = count($_POST['member']);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $fname = $_POST['member'][$i]['fname'];
    $lname = $_POST['member'][$i]['lname'];
}
```

How would I append the number contained in `$i` to `$fname` & `$lname` so that `$fname` & `$lname` become `$fname1` & `$lname_2` and so on? Or is there a better way of doing this? Nothing I have tried works.

Comment: What's your ultimate goal with this?

Comment: @TheSmose My main goal is to store all of the information in $_SESSION variables that can be retrieved later. Say there are 7 new "Contacts" added, I want to loop through the data and store each value to $_SESSION variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Answer to your new question - how to store in the session:

```
session_start();
$count = count($_POST['member']);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $_SESSION["fname_{$i}"] = $_POST['member'][$i]['fname'];
    $_SESSION["lname_{$i}"] = $_POST['member'][$i]['lname'];
}
```

Comment: My main goal is to store all of the information in $_SESSION variables that can be retrieved later. Say there are 7 new "Contacts" added, I want to loop through the data and store each value to $_SESSION variables

Comment: That's a different problem... will add a solution for that now

Comment: Awesome, I will test it out now. Will let you know how it goes

Comment: There you go... this will store values from the POST into the SESSION

Comment: Don't forget `session_start()` !!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20549/discussion-between-three3-and-thesmose)

Answer (score 1):

```
$i = 0;
$output = array();

foreach ($_POST['member'] as $member)
{
   $output['fname' . $i] = $member['fname'];   
   $output['lname' . $i] = $member['lname'];
   $i++;
}

extract($output);
```

Though..why?

Comment: snap... +1 for posting ahead of me using `extract`

Comment: @bigman My main goal is to store all of the information in $_SESSION variables that can be retrieved later. Say there are 7 new "Contacts" added, I want to loop through the data and store each value to $_SESSION variables

Comment: So change $output to $_SESSION..This is baddd practice man. At very least store $output into the session and exact that later..but hell, I would just find a better way to go about this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$count = count($_POST['member']);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
 $fname.'_'.$i = $_POST['member'][$i]['fname'];
 $lname.'_'.$i = $_POST['member'][$i]['lname'];
}
```

So you can access $fname_1,$fname_2 etc...

Answer (score -1):

Hi try the simple concatination(".") operator of php.. So your code will be

```
$count = count($_POST['member']);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $fname = $_POST['member']['fname'.$i];
    $lname = $_POST['member']['lname_'.$i];
}
```